# erlang-sqlite3 sqlite3:table_info error

Tags: sqlite, erlang

I tried to extract table info  from sqlite database using sqlite3:table_info/2 function and got an error message.

```
{ok,Pid} = sqlite3:open(db3).

Sql = <<"CREATE TABLE test (
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
           ts TEXT default (datetime('now')),
           key TEXT,
           val TEXT
           );">>.
sqlite3:sql_exec(db3,Sql).
```

Check table list:

```
sqlite3:list_tables(db3).
[test]
```

Try to get table info:

```
sqlite3:table_info(db3,test).
```

And now error message:

```
    `=ERROR REPORT==== 1-Mar-2015::19:37:46 ===
    ** Generic server db3 terminating 
    ** Last message in was {table_info,test}
    ** When Server state == {state,#Port,
                                   [{file,"../tmp/db3.sqlite"}],
                                   {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                         {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                          [],[],[]},
                                         {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                           [],[],[]}}}}
    ** Reason for termination == 
    ** {function_clause,[{sqlite3,build_constraints,
                                  [["INTEGER","PRIMARY","KEY"]],
                                  [{file,"src/sqlite3.erl"},{line,1169}]},
                         {sqlite3,build_table_info,2,
                                  [{file,"src/sqlite3.erl"},{line,1166}]},
                         {sqlite3,handle_call,3,
                                  [{file,"src/sqlite3.erl"},{line,833}]},
                         {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,
                                     [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,607}]},
                         {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                                     [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,639}]},
                         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                   [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}
    ** exception exit: function_clause
         in function  sqlite3:build_constraints/1
            called as sqlite3:build_constraints(["INTEGER","PRIMARY","KEY"])
         in call from sqlite3:build_table_info/2 (src/sqlite3.erl, line 1166)
         in call from sqlite3:handle_call/3 (src/sqlite3.erl, line 833)
         in call from gen_server:try_handle_call/4 (gen_server.erl, line 607)
         in call from gen_server:handle_msg/5 (gen_server.erl, line 639)
         in call from proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3 (proc_lib.erl, line 237)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a bug in `sqlite3.erl` (INTEGER is not a constraint). Anyway, trying to parse SQL is doomed to fail in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [fixed the problem](https://github.com/alexeyr/erlang-sqlite3/commit/32149a35ad323ca02864de309e89ebea31e665ab) with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. The `default` is harder to support, but I've added a fallback so it doesn't crash, at least. As @CL mentions, this parsing is unreliable anyway (since SQLite unfortunately doesn't expose any way to use its own parser).

Comment: Thanks.  sqlite3  command line tool has a command  .schema ?TABLE? that shows create statement for the table. Would it be possible to have something like this?  My suggestion is that in most cases  user want to see the structure of the table to understand how to work with it.

Comment: It is that create statement that we are trying to parse. If you need it, just sql_exec `"select sql from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'whatever_name' and type='table';"`

Comment: Another possibility would be to add `raw` option to `sqlite3:table_info` which doesn't parse anything and just returns the statement.

Comment: Looks like a good idea. I found an error in my create table script: it should be datetime('now') funciton.